# DirectShow.Net Problem Bridge Sample Filter Freeze video

Tags: c#, .net, video-capture, directshow.net

I've some troubles trying to make the DirectShowNet Bridge filter working. When I connect it to the rest of my graph, it just freezes everything (with one second delay), and then everything stop.
When I connect GraphEdit to the remote graph it's connected.

Does somebody knows anything about that ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Do you have a working, isolated test project and a README how to use it? If so, post a link and I will take a look.